# libpcap packet size

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libpcap

I'm working with libpcap in C on linux (centos) and I'm following [this guide](http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section4.html) I want to simply print out the entire packet in ascii and i'v managed to get it working by casting it a u_char* in the "my_callback" function. But I can't figure out how to get the length of the data. strstr didn't work. the header has a len member that you can access to get the size but I can't find anything similar for the *packet being passed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since I don't know, I am not posting it as an answer ... but it appears from some of the notes in the headers that the caplen member would be the length of the data.

Comment: The packet isn't going to be ASCII, so treating all the data bytes as an ASCII string won't work; in particular, using `strstr()` on it is a bad idea.  Read the code in that guide, which processes the packet data as *binary* data.  Einstein's answer is correct; use the `caplen` field of the `struct pcap_pkthdr` as the number of bytes of packet data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your callback the caplen member of the pkthdr variable (see struct pcap_pkthdr) contains the size of the *captured* packet.

For example assume a packet is captured.  The total length of the frame is 1024 bytes.  However the capture driver only captured the first 128 bytes of the frame and made it available to your callback.

In this case you should expect pkthdr->caplen to be 128 and header->len to be 1024.

Answer (score 1):

The total packet size is at the "total length" field at the ip header (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header#Total_Length).

How to get that value with libpcap can be found at this example: http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c

You just have to get the value of the field that references to the "total length" (named ip_len) from this variable:

```
const struct sniff_ip *ip;              /* The IP header */
```

Comment: No, that's the total length of an IPv4 packet; not all packets are IPv4 packets (they might be IPv6 packets, ARP packets, or various other types of packets), and the length of the IPv4 packet isn't the length of the entire packet on the network in most cases - for example, for Ethernet, there's also the 14-byte Ethernet header and, if the length of the IPv4 packet + 14 is less than 60, there's also an Ethernet trailer to pad the packet to 60 bytes (64 bytes if you include the CRC) on the Ethernet segment.

Comment: Is there any way to get the packet length using libpcap, independently of the packet type (ip, arp, icmp...)?

Comment: Yes - the `len` field of the `struct pcap_pkthdr` is the actual length of the packet on the wire/on the air (although, for "on the air", note that on most platforms, unless you're capturing in monitor mode, 802.11 packets are transformed to "fake Ethernet" packets, and the "len" field gives the fake length of the fake Ethernet packet, not the real length of the 802.11 packet "on the air").  That's *NOT* necessarily the amount of actual packet data you have in the capture, however - that's `caplen`.

Comment: Don't know what to do, I'd like to delete my answer because it's wrong but maybe useful for other people.

Comment: Also, packets might have a "pseudo-header", containing "metadata" about the packet, before the actual "on the wire"/"on the air" link-layer header.  For example, a packet captured in monitor mode on an 802.11 interface might have a [radiotap header](http://www.radiotap.org) giving information such as signal strength.  If such a header is present, the value in `caplen` and `len` include the length of the metadata header as well as the length of the packet "on the wire"/"on the air".